# How to interrupt accept() in a TCP/IP server?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a vision-application, which have two modes:
1) parameter setting
2) automatic
The problem is in 2), when my app waits for a signal via TCP/IP. The program is freezing while `accept()`-methode is called. I want to provide the possibility on a GUI to change the mode. So if the mode is changing, it's provided by another signal (message_queue). So I want to interrupt the accept state.
Is there a simple possibility to interrupt the accept?

```
std::cout << "TCPIP " << std::endl;

client = accept(slisten, (struct sockaddr*)&clientinfo, &clientinfolen);

if (client != SOCKET_ERROR)
    cout << "client accepted: " << inet_ntoa(clientinfo.sin_addr) << ":"
         << ntohs(clientinfo.sin_port) << endl;

//receive the message from client
//recv returns the number of bytes received!!
//buf contains the data received
int rec = recv(client, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
cout << "Message: " << rec << " bytes and the message   " << buf << endl;
```

I read about `select()` but I have no clue how to use it. Could anybody give me a hint how to implement for example `select()` in my code?

Thanks.

Best regards,

T

Comment: Multithreading (separating rendering from the actual process or having the threads render distinct parts of the window) is not an acceptable solution?

Comment: The problem is,that I can't leave the freeze state caused by accept(). I have to interrupt it for checking the mode again.

Comment: Interaction between GUI and network io may depend on the OS. What is yours, or do you really need a fully portable way (probaly harder...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to run `select` in a loop with a timeout.

Put `slisten` into nonblocking mode (this isn't strictly necessary but sometimes `accept` blocks even when `select` says otherwise) and then:

```
fd_set read_fds;
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
FD_SET(slisten, &read_fds);

struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 1;  // 1s timeout
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

int select_status;
while (true) {
    select_status = select(slisten+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (select_status == -1) {
        // ERROR: do something
    } else if (select_status > 0) {
        break;  // we have data, we can accept now
    }
    // otherwise (i.e. select_status==0) timeout, continue
}

client = accept(slisten, ...);
```

This will allow you to catch signals once per second. More info here:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html

and Windows version (pretty much the same):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @T_F It does work on Windows. You just need appropriate headers (and with this I cannot help you, try googling).

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer Op's question. `accept()` creates a new socket fd, where as `select()` doesn't do that. It only scans existing sockets. That manpage is terribly unhelpful, as most manpages are.

Comment: @Cerin I think you misunderstand the solution. In my code I still use accept. The difference is that with select I know that accept will not block, because there is a pending socket. Select is used only for timeout.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to call accept() only when there is an incoming connection request. You do that by polling on the listen socket, where you can also add other file descriptors, use a timeout etc.

You did not mention your platform. On Linux, see epoll(), UNIX see poll()/select(), Windows I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

A general way would be to use a local TCP connection by which the UI thread could interrupt the `select` call. The general architecture would use:

- a dedicated thread waiting with `select` on both `slisten` and the local TCP connection
- a TCP connection (Unix domain socket on a Unix or Unix-like system, or 127.0.0.1 on Windows) between the UI thread and the waiting one
- various synchronizations/messages between both threads as required

Just declare that `select` should read `slisten` and the local socket. It will return as soon as one is ready, and you will be able to know which one is ready.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't specified your platform, and networking, especially async, is platform-specific, I suppose you need a cross-platform solution. `Boost.Asio` fits perfectly here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload1.html

Example from the link:

```
void accept_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  if (!error)
  {
    // Accept succeeded.
  }
}

...

boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service);
...
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
acceptor.async_accept(socket, accept_handler);
```

If `Boost` is a problem, [Asio](http://think-async.com/Asio) can be a header-only lib and used w/o Boost: http://think-async.com/Asio/AsioAndBoostAsio.

Comment: I believe that every platform supports select syscall. And OP is interested in it.

Comment: Boost is awesome..but gosh, that example reminds me why I don't use it. SO MANY COLONS!